# Was "Ralph Breaks the Internet" the first Disney production to feature computer-animated renditions of these characters?

Tags: animation, ralph-breaks-the-internet

"Ralph Breaks the Internet" famously features most Disney princesses together sharing the same scene. While this includes modern computer-animated characters like Anna, Elsa, Merida, Moana and Rapunzel which appear to be nearly identical to their versions in the original movies; it also features some princesses which I've only seen in [traditional (hand-drawn) animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_animation) (ignoring live-action versions for the purposes of this question).

These characters include:

- Ariel
- Aurora
- Belle
- Cinderella
- Mulan
- Jasmine
- Pocahontas
- Snow White

Admittedly, I can't say I've seen *every* Disney spin-off or short that these characters appear in. I've only seen the main theatrical movies related to each character.

My question is this: **Were the computer-animated versions of these characters, and their costumes designs, created brand-new for "Ralph Breaks the Internet", or have these versions appeared previously in some other Disney production and the costume designs are based on (or at least resemble) those?**

I realize that the "comfy clothes" designs are new. I'm talking about the scene in which they appear in their more traditional attire:

[image: CG Princesses]

Comment: As clarification, are you interested in ANY Disney production, or just movies? Say, would you accept videogame 3d renders?

Comment: @GGMG Any official Disney production is fair game. Movies, shorts, cartoon shows... and yes games. As long as they feature 3d characters like the ones shown here.

Comment: Gotcha. I added my answer, the series Kingdom Hearts have 3D renders of the princesses that predate RBtI by almost a decade. Unfortunately, now your title and comment don't match, I'd advise you update your question to reflect you're not just looking for movies.

Comment: What what? Cinderella's dress is white. Source: VHS

Comment: Hey Tushar Raj, I know you've already elaborated on this but I think I can help improve this question if you are still interested and I just wanted to make sure I have this right before I put any effort into it. I believe you're interested in 2 things: when were they first CGI'ed and when did they first wear the costumes shown in Ralph Breaks the Internet, right? (I think when you say 'design' this is the specific design aspect you are interested in.)

Comment: Ok Tushar Raj, I've jiggled things around a little and tried to add a little more emphasis to costume design whilst still not invalidating existing answers. I'm still a little perplexed though as to what differences you think there are to their costumes in other films, the fact you refer to them as being in their 'traditional' costumes kinda shows that they are in the ones they always are? Perhaps you can further detail what you think is different?

Comment: Side note - By 'improve this question' I'd actually planned on adding images of the character designs from Wreck's The Internet into one of the answers below to help with the comparison of costume designs (i.e. improve the question overall by improving the answers) but then I realised that I can't actually get those images until the DVD comes out!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Not if we're counting videogames.

The game series Kingdom Hearts, an official Disney/Square Enix joint production, has 3D renders of your mentioned characters, along with almost every "official" Disney princess (and a few unofficial ones).

In your order:

Ariel:

[image: Ariel]

Aurora:

[image: Aurora]

Belle:

[image: Belle]

Cinderella:

[image: Cinderella]

Mulan:

[image: Mulan]

Jasmine:

[image: Jasmine]

Snow White:

[image: Snow White]

Interestingly enough, the only princess you mentioned that hasn't made it into the games yet is Pocahontas. In that case, this might be her first 3D outing.

Comment: +1. Thanks. Wasn't aware of this. Have to say that these versions look significantly less detailed than the Ralph versions. But it's something.

Comment: @TusharRaj As GGMG noted in their comment, some of the Kingdom Hearts games are over a decade old at this point, so with the progress of technology, the models will naturally look outdated compared to the ones in Ralph Breaks The Internet.

Comment: @F1Krazy Additionally, there's usually a difference between real-time rendered game graphics and prerendered videos (though that difference has been getting smaller as time goes on).

Comment: @JAB I want to emphasize that a little; even modern AAA games have a tiny, tiny fraction as many polygons as a single scene in a 3D movie. The gap is closing mostly because we're discovering tricks that, while you're distracted by a game, you don't notice. There's a reason movies need massive render farms to compile everything in under a year and Just Cause 3 can run on my dinky laptop.

Comment: @Nic I’d actually flip that around: there’s a difference *because* movies can accept massive render farms working for a year to produce a final scene, while games have to run in real time on dinky laptops. That’s why the difference in detail hasn’t narrowed as much as you might expect — as computers get more powerful and games can have more detailed graphics, movies also use the increased power to improve *their* graphics instead of to cut rendering resources.

Comment: The now sadly defuncy Disney Infinity game had some of the characters as well - Tinkerbell (not a princess proper), Jasmine, and Mulan

Comment: These versions look much more faithful to the originals than the Ralph versions. Cinderella still looks mostly like an (animated) adult human, rather than a toddler of some humanoid species, for example.

Comment: @cpast I really don't get the distinction you're making. Game graphics uses tricks that render farms can't (or at least, wouldn't be cost-effective) like prebaking static shadows, vastly simplified math to calculate reflections and diffusion, etc. Sure, as the raw computing power increases, render farms get better, but the tricks used by games don't... really apply to render farms, because the game tricks are all about invisibly sacrificing quality for performance, whereas render farms go in exactly the opposite direction.

Answer (score 24):

A few of the princesses also appeared in Disney Junior's animated show Sofia the First.

From [Disney movie list](https://disneymovieslist.com/2018/03/19/list-of-disney-princesses-who-appeared-in-sofia-the-first-and-when/):

Ariel, Aurora, Belle, Cinderella, Mulan, Jasmine and Snow White appeared in the series. Only Pocahontas has not been in the show.

**Ariel**:

[image]

**Aurora**:

[image]

**Belle**:

[image]

**Cinderella**:

[image]

**Mulan**:

[image]

**Jasmine**:

[image]

**Snow White**:

[image]

Comment: +1. Thanks. This answer illustrates my point. Though these are indeed CG appearences predating Ralph, I wouldn't say they resemble the character designs shown in the movie.

Comment: @TusharRaj, the thing is, the character designs for Ralph 2 are new because they're made to match the movie's art style. Even Elsa, Anna and Rapunzel are different. They didn't reuse the previous models. So, what's exactly your question?

Comment: @Arturo: *Were the computer-animated versions of these characters created brand-new for "Ralph Breaks the Internet"* This.

Comment: @TusharRaj, your question seems ambiguous, because the 3D princesses have more than one computer-animated version. Rapunzel has 4 versions (original, Sofia the 1st, Kingdom Hearts, Ralph 2). There's no "the" computer animated version.

Comment: @Arturo My question couldn't be clearer. You're the first one to call it ambiguous. I'm not asking for all existing 3D versions. "The" version I'm taking about is Ralph, and the questions asks if it's new or not. I don't know how you fail to see that even after I quoted it verbatim from the OP. If you know of any versions not mentioned on this page, please post it. Otherwise, this discussion is pointless.

Comment: @TusharRaj, I call it ambiguous because after having clear answers to your question, you seem to complain they don't resemble the character designs shown in Ralph 2. So, that led me to believe there's 2 questions. 1) Are there other 3D versions of the 2D princesses? 2) Are the specific character designs in Ralph 2 newly created for the movie? The current answers answer 1), but you seem to be asking for 2).

Comment: When I asked the question, I assumed that any 3D versions, if they existed, would be consistent with what was shown in Ralph. This turned out not to be the case. Hence the unintended "ambiguity". I am asking for (2). And my comment isn't a complaint; it's an observation. The current answer is acccepted because I feel it's closer to the Ralph version than the Sofia ones (hint: sleeves); and the point other community members made about it lacking detail because it's older and for a game.